# ChannelFactory очистка данных

Tags: c#, wcf

При передаче большого объема данных в WCF службу, передаваемое приложение начинает безмерно потреблять ОЗУ *240>364>478>797* Мб и т.д. Попытка очистить больше не используемую память не удалась.

Что пробовал:

1. Очистка потока StringWriter Stream
2. Очистка переменных типов XmlSerializer и FileStream
3. GC.SuppressFinalize(this) и GC.Collect();
4. Закрытие канала

**Как еще можно очистить ОЗУ после передачи данных WCF сервису.**

```
                                int CopiedSize = 0;
                                byte[] FileByte = new byte[RemainingSize];
                                while ((CountCell = CurrentFile.Read(FileByte, _Offset, RemainingSize - _Offset)) > 0)
                                {
                                    _Offset += CountCell;  // опеределяем необходимое количество строк в байтовом массиве путем смещения 
                                }
                                CurrentFile.Flush();
                                CurrentFile.Close();
                                CurrentFile.Dispose();
```

Comment: Покажите как вы освобождаете память.

Comment: Подготовьте минимальный пример утекающей службы и прикрепите код к вопросу. У меня службы работают без перезапуска месяцами и не видел, чтобы память текла вёдрами. Возможно, что вы что-то делаете не так - для этого нужен ваш код в вопросе.

Comment: добавил код в во

Comment: Это не минимальный пример! И он не воспроизводим. Я не могу его взять и запустить.

Comment: Скиньте весь код вашей функции !! Больше всего меня смущает этот код
CopiedSize = CopiedSize + 1000000; Что это за объект ??
MainForm.ValueSoftwareForPC.ListDataTabControl[_iNdex].FileByte

Comment: И не надо писать *"Скиньте весь код вашей функции"* - потому что функция у него большая, и весь код закроют даже быстрее чем вопрос без кода.

Comment: Ну тут как минимум можно обратить внимание это на `using` и одновременное использование метода `Close()` -> `Dispose()` где нет вызова метода `Flush()`.

Comment: добавил код в во

Answer (score 0):

Обнаружил что источником проблемы служит массив

```
byte[] FileByte = new byte[RemainingSize];
```

даже если его очистить, после использования

```
Array.Clear(FileByte,0, FileByte.Length);
FileByte = null;
FileByte = new byte[1];
GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration);
GC.Collect();
```

объем используемой ОЗУ не уменьшается

Comment: Наверняка этот массив попадает в кучу больших объектов (LOH), которая не дефрагментируется по умолчанию, в отличие от кучи маленьких объектов. Если используете фреймворк последних версий, то можно и LOH компактировать. См. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/592561/184217