# OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, исключения, outofmemoryerror

У меня есть метод в классе, который создает список моих линий. Количество точек в одной линии может достигать 1700000 и больше.

```
private unsafe List<Line> GetLinesData()
    {
        var lineData = new short[LineCount];
        for (var i = 0; i < LineCount; i++)
        {
            _allLineData.Add(new Line(i));
        }
        if (DbHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            fixed (int* linesPointer = _lines)
            {
                fixed (short* lineDataPointer = lineData)
                {
                    for (var i = 10; i < DataCount - 10; i++)
                    {
                        var errorCode = NativeMethods.GetIndexDataSet(DbHandle, linesPointer, LineCount, i, lineDataPointer);
                        if (errorCode != Result.ErrorOk) continue;
                        for (var j = 0; j < LineCount; j++)
                        {
                            var point = new LinePoint(i - 10, lineData[j]);
                            _allLineData[j].Points.Add(point);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return _allLineData;
    }
```

Этот метод есть в двух моих приложениях и в одном он отрабатывает нормально, но  в другом кидает OutOfMemoryException + для релиз версии ошибка появляется еще раньше.
Вот память процесса для двух программ, при вызове этого метода:

Без ошибки
[image: Без ошибки]

С ошибкой

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В общем я не понимаю, почему не хватает памяти. И я не могу поставить платформу x64, так как используется dll x32.
Надеюсь, что понятно объяснил)

Comment: 1гб памяти, хм, думаете это правильных подход?

Comment: Заменил LinePoint на структуру и процесс использует 800 МБ, но проблема с другой программой все еще остается. И как можно оптимизировать потребность в хранении такого большого количества точек?

Comment: а почему LinePoint

Comment: @Санитариум это просто моя структура точки

Comment: Так как мы не видим большую часть вашего кода, будем действовать методом тыка. Попробуйте изменить третий параметр в пятой строке седьмого метода...

Comment: Список `points` создается, но не используется - зачем он? Из метода возвращается `_allLineData` - это поле класса, доступное и так; поэтому возврат выглядит странно. Не ясен смысл использования unsafe-кода. Без него никак? Когда данные пришпилены (fixed) в памяти, это сильно мешает работе сборщика мусора и менеджера памяти - ведь они вынуждены обруливать эти куски данных.

Comment: А вам эти точки в таком кол-ве нужны в один момент времени? Я к тому, что может быть имеет смысл сбрасывать данные на диск используя какую-нибудь SQLLite

Comment: См. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/592561/184217. И разрешите в настройках использовать большие объекты: [gcAllowVeryLargeObjects](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/gcallowverylargeobjects-element).

Answer (score 1):

Вы столкнулись с интересным явлением, которое называется "фрагментация памяти". Поздравляем. Оно происходит, когда перераспределение большого куска памяти для его увеличения (`_allLineData[j].Points.Add(point);`) перемежается с созданием некоторого количества небольших объектов (`var point = new LinePoint(...);`). Заказывайте количество элементов в `_allLineData[j].Points` сразу или вообще используйте массив.