# Работа со сборщиком мусора в c#

Tags: c#, память, сборщик-мусора

Хотелось бы узнать некоторые нюансы работы со сборщиком мусора:

1. Надо ли его иногда в программе вызывать в ручную
2. Когда существует действительная необходимость пользоваться сборщиком мусора непосредственным вызовом метода `Gc.Collect()`?

Comment: Ещё нюансы: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/592561/184217

Answer (score 0, accepted):

За вызов сборщика мусора обычно отвечает сама .NET. `Gc.Collect()`, если верить [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.gc.collect?view=netframework-4.8), может инициировать сборку мусора принудительно.

Вызывать `Gc.Collect()` имеет смысл для очистки памяти, когда у Вас есть подозрения, что у Вас накопилось много ненужных объектов. Также нередко вызывают `Gc.Collect()` в методе `Dispose()`, чтобы освободить память после использования уже ненужного объекта.

Comment: А имеет смысл, например, вызывать `Gc.Collect()`, например, раз в 5 минут, или это не имеет смысла?

Comment: У Вас раз в 5 минут создаётся столько объектов?

Comment: Вызов по таймеру, 99,9999...% случаев ничем не оправдан. Только процессорное время потратите.

Comment: Впервые слышу, что бы кто-то вызывал `GC.Collect` в `Dispose`. У вас есть примеры?

Comment: Вызывать GC в методе Dispose нет вообще никакого смысла, т.е. раз этот метод сейчас выполняется - то объект, для которого этот метод вызван - напрямую достижим и является GC Root. Соберет что угодно, но уж точно не его.